# How to get typing characters during typing in Microsoft BOT Emulator?

Tags: c#, frameworks, botframework, bots, chatbot

I'm creating a Chatbot project in `(C#, Microsoft BOT Framework)` where I need to capture each characters being typed by the user before sending it to emulator window, so I can use these typing characters for another purpose.

Any ideas, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the input field in BotChat to monitor for `keyup` events and use the key strokes however you'd like before the user sends the message. See the example code below.

```
const input = document.getElementsByClassName('wc-shellinput')[0];

input.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.key != 'Enter') {
    console.log('Key:', event.key);
    console.log('Value:', event.target.value);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.